# How can i achieve/make a listView on camera screen?

Tags: java, android-studio

I already made a list view, on the camera, but its invisible, maybe because it needs a background to appear. I want to make the listView visible on the camera screen because it contains filters.
[it looks like this now:
The listView is invisible, but there because when you click the area the filters work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCRL6.jpg)

[I want it to look like this: I want the list view visible on camera.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuXPY.jpg)

I hope i explained well, if not please ask.

Here is the adapter:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.anisacoding.expriment.R;

import java.util.List;
public class FilterAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FilterType> {

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
    }
    private final Context context;
    private final List<FilterType> values;
    private boolean isWhite = false;
    public FilterAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<FilterType> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
        values = objects;
    }
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        // reuse views
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if (isWhite) {
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_white_text, null);
            } else {
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_text, null);
            }


            // configure view holder
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        String s = values.get(position).name();
        holder.text.setText(s);
        return rowView;
    }

    public FilterAdapter whiteMode() {
        isWhite = true;
        return this;
    }
    

}
```

This is text of the list view layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    style="@style/ServiceTextShadow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:textSize="15sp" >
</TextView>
```

This is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/filter_list"
        android:layout_width="129dp"
        android:layout_height="717dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btn_record"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

    </ListView>




    <com.anisacoding.expriment.VideoEditorFolder.widget.PortraitFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrap_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">


    </com.anisacoding.expriment.VideoEditorFolder.widget.PortraitFrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_record"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/record_Video"
        android:text="@string/app_record"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.454"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.926"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_btn_record" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_switch_camera"
        android:layout_width="71dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:text="@string/SWITCH"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.91"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.052"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_switch"
        android:contentDescription="@string/SWITCH" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_flash"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/flash"
        android:text="@string/flash"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.95"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_flash" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pause_video"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/record_Video"
        android:text="@string/pause"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.454"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.926"
        android:color="#FF0000"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_stop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/music_library"
        android:layout_width="52dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/library_music"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.45"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/btn_record"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline18"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.926"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_music_golibrary" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.7347932" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timer2"
        android:layout_width="53dp"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="@string/_2_m"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#Ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline18"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_flash" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [The camera activity i created isnt transparent. ListView isnt showing, how can i make the activity transparent so ListView will be visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63974573/the-camera-activity-i-created-isnt-transparent-listview-isnt-showing-how-can-i)

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, or any new code you've tried, will bump it to the top of the active queue.